# Extracting text from html tags with regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-2.7, web-scraping

I'm new to web scraping and regular expressions. Figured out how to extract text between html tags. Problem is I don't want the text inside the tags, such as class=" ", just the text in between tags.

I've got:

```
    re.findall(r'(<h(.*?)</h(.*?)>)', html)
```

Which gives me:

```
    <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
```

But I only want: Title

By the way, I'm using Python 2.7.10 with urllib2 and re imported.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the capturing round brackets brackets and put a closing `>` for opening h tag.

```
re.findall(r'<h.*?>(.*?)</h[0-9]>', html1)
```

[live demo](https://regex101.com/r/lG4pJ4/1)

However I would recommend using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for scraping , it is an excellent library written for web scraping. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: When running that code it only extracted the first letter in each header. So for "Title" it extracted "T".

Comment: @VillaRava What is your input? May be you can try dropping lazy quantifier, but that would also consider the text upto the next closing of `h` tag

Comment: This is the first header on the site I'm trying to scrape: <h2 class="masthead-title">Medieval Tones</h2>. I get "M".

Comment: That's quite strange because I get the full text.

Comment: Could it be something else about the code? Although I doubt it. I can post it in full, some 8 lines of code.

Comment: I'm starting over with BeautifulSoup4. But I have a hard time figuring out the  bs4 equivalent of re.findall(r'<h.*?>(.*?)</h[0-9]>', html1)?